# understanding destructor in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

As we all know, when a function returns, stack-allocated objects would be reclaimed and the associated destructors would be invoked before that. My question is: how is a memory location determined to represent objects so that we can call the destructor? And is there any run-time overhead incurred to do this?

Comment: The memory location is an implementation detail; why are you concerned?  Also, what runtime are you using?  Are you running on a virtual machine, or a native instruction set?

Comment: Are you asking how the implementation knows what stack objects need to be destroyed and where they are located?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is a memory location determined to represent objects so that we can call the destructor?

Memory location does not determine when the constructor gets called. The compiler knows which variables are allocated on the stack and creates the appropriate code to call the corresponding destructors.

At least, they are normally on the stack. The point is the same logic could be used regardless of where the memory was stored. Being stored on the stack simply means that they need to be called one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but the memory location of stack-allocated objects are known at compile time.  There is no run-time overhead to determine their location.

Comment: Is it correct that: pointers to these objects are known at compile time, and calls to destructors are inserted by the compiler in the postlogue of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The location of stack allocated objects is calculated as an offset to the current stack pointer position so actually there is no calculation needed.

Unlike heap allocated objects in which the dynamic memory manager has to decide where the object will be allocated, the stack is just lineary and grows accordingly to the need, at compile time the compiler will know that an object, for example, resides at current pointer less a specified amount of bytes and will use that value throughout the binary code whenever that variable is needed.